Disable hash generation in isolated stylesheet filename of razor class libraries in a Blazor Web App
I have a .NET 8 Blazor web app named Contoso which includes Razor class libraries LibA and LibB. LibA is in the same Visual Studio solution, and LibB is in another solution.
When I start the web app, it generates the stylesheet for all libraries on the fly. I can see that in the file https://localhost:0000/Contoso.styles.css that imports all stylesheets with the CSS from the components:
@import '_content/LibA/LibA.bundle.scp.css';
@import '_content/LibB/LibB.ca3u9u6gjt.bundle.scp.css';

All external libraries like LibB have a dynamic token ca3u9u6gjt in the stylesheet name. This changes every time the library is updated and has style changes.
How can I disable this behaviour and remove the hash?
We have to include the filenames directly because some have to be in a correct order. But I don't want to change the filename after every update. This behaviour is only since Net8.
What did I try so far?
I added this to the .csproj file of the web app and of LibB, but it does not change anything:
<PropertyGroup>
    <CssScopedGenerateSourceHash>false</CssScopedGenerateSourceHash>
</PropertyGroup>

Update
When i generate the package in the Package Manager Console with 'dotnet pack' it generates 'LibB.bundle.scp.css' as wanted. The hash is added when package is generated with the command "pack" (DotNetCoreCLI@2) in our Azure-Devops-Pipeline.

Hi cpt.oneeye, may I know where you find the CssScopedGenerateSourceHash setting ? As far as I know, we can disable CSS isolation by using <ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>.

@JasonPan Hi Jason. It was a suggestion from AI-Chat. But i was sceptical in the first place because i couldn't find anything about it elsewhere. I dont want to disable css isolation completely. I just want to get rid of the hash. It has something todo with our production pipeline (see edited post).

It's Fingerprinting assets feature to prevent reusing old versions of files.
If you want to disable fingerprint of static assets, I suggest you should use .Net9, and use below settings.
<PropertyGroup>
  <StaticWebAssetFingerprintingEnabled>false</StaticWebAssetFingerprintingEnabled>
  <StaticWebAssetsFingerprintContent>false</StaticWebAssetsFingerprintContent>
</PropertyGroup>


I can't use Net9 because it has no longterm support. But nonetheless this worked. The devops-pipeline interprets this property and the file is added to the nugetpackage without fingerprint. Thank you.
